# Expected number of trials for either A or B to occur

Tags: probability, expected-value

Suppose we are playing a game where the player gets 3 points for a win, 1 point for a draw and 0 points for a loss. The probabilities are as follows

P(Win) = 0.2

P(Draw) = 0.5

P(Loss) = 0.3

What is the expected number of games before a player has 3 points or more?

I am unsure quite how to approach the problem, the expected number of games for a win would be 5 and the expected number of games for 3 draws would be 6 games so we would expect it to take less than 5 games to reach the 3 point threshold. My instinct would be to add together the probabilities in some way but I think that needing at least 3 games to get the points via draws is confusing me.

Comment: You can expect $0.2\cdot 3+0.5\cdot 1+0.3\cdot 0=1.1$ per round. So the expected number of games would be $3$. As you have an expected number of points of 3.3 after 3 games.

Comment: I understand the expected points per game calculation but when it comes to using that to get the expected number of games I'm unsure when that is valid, for example if we were to alter the point scoring to 50 points for a win keeping everything else the same we would get 0.2 * 50 + 0.5 * 1 + 0.3 * 0 = 10.5 per round so our expected number of games would be 1 game even though these should be the same problem i.e how many games until 1 win or 3 draws. In the 50 point example it's clear how I've skewed it because the extra points don't mean anything. So does this occur in my original example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the expected count for trials until the earliest of the first win or the third draw.

That is: $1 +$ the expected count of trials where no win or at most two draws have occurred.

Let $X_k$ be the indicator for the event that no win or at most two draws have occurred on or before trial $k$.

The probability that this event occurs is: $\mathsf E(X_k) $

And so the expected count you seek is: $1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \mathsf E(X_k)$

Your task is to evaluate that probability and find the closed form for the series.

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of the expectation we get:

$$ E[X] = \overset{\text{win}}{0.2} \cdot \overset{\text{pts.}}{3} \cdot \overset{\text{no. of games}}{X} + 0.5 \cdot 1 \cdot X + 0.3 \cdot 0 \cdot X = 1.1X$$

You basically need to check when $$ 1.1X \geq 3$$
This is not a whole number, but use the fact that $X$ is a natural number (you can't have half games / negative games right? ). So you will need to choose the closest whole number to $\frac{3}{1.1}$

Comment: I understand the expected points per game calculation but when it comes to using that to get the expected number of games I'm unsure when that is valid, for example if we were to alter the point scoring to 50 points for a win keeping everything else the same we would get 0.2 * 50 + 0.5 * 1 + 0.3 * 0 = 10.5 per round so our expected number of games would be 1 game even though these should be the same problem i.e how many games until 1 win or 3 draws. In the 50 point example it's clear how I've skewed it because the extra points don't mean anything. So does this occur in my original example?

Comment: @Anon051389 This is the point of the expectation, it cares about the value and the probability of each incident to happen, then it outputs the expected number of points you get in $x$ games, what if I told you that the expectation of rolling a dice one time is $3.5$ clearly there is not number $3.5$ on the die, but this is the correct interpretation of the expectation.